# error connecting client server [Host lookup failed [0]:]

Tags: php

I tried to connect client server but end with the following error on the client side.

> Host lookup failed [0]:

What could be the possible solution?

```
<?php
$host    = "192.168.1.7";
$port    = 2300;
$message = "Hello Server";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to     server\n");  
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to    server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
// close socket
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I wanna connect a simple php client to a php server .. The server and the client are in two different systems in the same network though .. I use Apache thru xampp..

THIS WAS THE ACTUAL ERROR

> Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: Host lookup failed [0]: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. in D:\Program Files\XAMPP\htdocs\php\client.php on line 9
>   Could not connect to server

Comment: SHow the code that is causing the error

Comment: Umm, what are you doing?  Connect what client?  To what server?  Using what protocol?  We're gonna need to see your code to even begin to figure out how to help you.

Comment: I have edited ma question ^

Comment: `1292.168.1.7` isn't a valid IP address. (I presume you really want `192.168.1.7`?)

Comment: Yea yea .. Sorry .. Thats the case .. 192.168.1.7

Comment: Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [0]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ..

This also stays as an issue.. 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a server running on `192.168.1.7`?  What is the server code?  Is the port open on that machine's firewall?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Client Server program to connect between two systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841183/client-server-program-to-connect-between-two-systems)

Answer (score 1):

```
$host    = "1292.168.1.7";
```

This doesn't look like a valid IP address. It should probably be of the form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (with xxx being a number between 1 and 255).

> Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect
>   [0]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

Your script can connect to the specified IP address only if there is a server running on this IP address and on the port you specified in your script. Check that the server is running, is accepting connections (is there a firewall?) and that the port is correct.

Comment: Sorrry .. That was a typing mistake . 
Its actually 192.168.1.7

Comment: Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [0]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ..

This also stays as an issue.. 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
$host    = "1292.168.1.7";
```

I suspect you meant

```
$host    = "192.168.1.7";
```

Comment: or just $host = "localhost";
If your db is on the same machine

Comment: no. localhost is 127.0.0.1

Comment: I know.. but "localhost" works fine as well.

Comment: No. He wanted `192.168.1.7`. It is not `localhost`, even if hosted on the same machine. Even if hosted on locahost `192.168.1.7` is not localhost alias.

Comment: Might be right on Windows, I don't know. But on Linux it is the same. Sorry nevermind ;)

Comment: You seem to not understand what I talk about.

Comment: I dont use a db here ..
I just wanna pass a message from client to server and display it there! **Client and server are two different systems in the same network!**

Comment: I get this error ..

**Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [0]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. ..**

Comment: it's quite self explanatory I think

Comment: Check firewall on the db server and open ports